# Why is my counter in python not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have just started learning Python and I need to make a list of certain values. See code below. My counter doesn't seem to be working however. It just takes the first num and doesn't change it. For instance, when I try size 5, I get a list of all 25, instead of 25 24 23 22 ...
My counter isn't doing anything. I've tried placing it elsewhere in the code, but nothing changes. Any help?

```
def listmaker(size):   
    listsize = size * size
    list = []
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            counter = 0
            num = listsize - counter
            if number > 0 :
                elem = num
                list.append(elem)   
            elif number == 0:
                elem = "X"     
    counter = counter + 1  
    print(list)
```

output I get with for instance 4 as size:

```
16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16....(times 16)
```

what I want it to be:

```
16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9...
```

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about what you expect your output to be?

Comment: You modify `counter`'s value outside the loop.

Comment: Additional pro-tip: `counter += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all your errors are in the comments

```
def listmaker(size):   
    listsize = size * size
    list = []
    # you should init counter outside the loops
    counter = 0
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            num = listsize - counter
            # number -> num
            if num > 0 :
                elem = num
                list.append(elem) 
            # number -> num  
            elif num == 0:
                elem = "X"   
            # you should modify the counter in the loop  
            counter = counter + 1  
    print(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `counter = 0` to before the loop, so that it is only run once, and move the `counter = counter + 1` (equivalent to `counter += 1` by the way) to the end of the second loop so it is run repeatedly after everything else.

Also, your `elif number==0:` is useless, because the loop will be run only 25 times, and that would activate after 26 times.

If you want do do this effectively, you could just use `list(range(size**2, 0, -1))`

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get integers from `size` squared to one, just do

```
list(range(size**2, 0, -1))
```

The `-1` step tells `range` to count down.  Use `range(size**2, -1, -1)` if you want the list to stop at `0` instead of `1`

Comment: good solution, but you do not really answer author's question. He want to know the errors in his code.